# Undefined reference when calling c function from assembly x86 32 bit

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have two files in my CodeBlocks project, main.c, functioninA.s. main.c contains a declaration of an assembly function functioninA.s with extern keyword, a function which I am trying to call from assembly sprintfkeys() with extern keyword as well, and other stuff. functioninA.s contains:

```
.global _galoislfsrina
.extern sprintfkeys

_galoislfsrina:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

movl 8(%ebp), %ebx   # GET seedIN
movl %ebx, %esi      # make a copy of seedIN
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx  # GET charCount
movl 16(%ebp), %edx  # GET &key[0]
movl $0, %edi

pushl %ebx # save caller-saved registers
pushl %esi
pushl %edi

loop:
    andl $1, %ebx  # generate LSB (output)
    shrl $1, %esi  # apply shift (LFSR_STATE)
    cmpl $0, %ebx  # compare LSB : 0
    jle noMask     # jump if LSB is 1
    xorl $0xA3000000, %esi # apply taps
    noMask:
    incl %edi          # period++

    pushl %edx         # pass keyPtr as arg1
    pushl %esi         # pass LFSR_STATE as arg2
    call sprintfkeys   # sprintfkeys(keyPtr, LFSR_STATE)
    popl %edx          # clean up the stack
    popl %esi          # ...

    addl %eax, %edx # keyPtr += sprintfKeys(keyPtr, LFSR_STATE)
    movl %edi, %ebx # ...
    shll $4, %ebx   # 4*period
    cmpl %ecx, %ebx # compare 4*period : charCount
    jge end         # break if 4*period >= charCount
    cmpl %esi, 16(%ebp) # compare startingState : LFSR_STATE
    jne loop
end:
popl %ebx # save caller-saved registers
popl %esi
popl %edi
movl $1, %eax # return 1
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

When I run the code, I get this error on `call sprintfkeys` line:

```
D:\folder\newf\Vernam Again\galoislfsrina.s|28|undefined reference to `sprintfkeys'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
```

So, is this a legit way to call a function? If it is, how do I get this assembly function know that it exists in main.c? I thought, `.extern sprintfkeys` would be enough.

Comment: Did you link with `main.o`?

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: `gcc functioninA.o main.o -o executableName`

Comment: Do you need to call/declare `_sprintfkeys`?  Like you used a prefix underscore for `_galoislfsrina`?